# How do I populate a select input based on 2 radio button values, from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I have a registration form for archery contests and I want users to select 2 things (their age category and their bow type).
Once those 2 are selected, I want the next field (select) to show up and be populated with information from my mysql database.
This field is a selection of shooting levels, differenciated in classes.

In the database, I have 4 tables.
1 for age category (id, name)
1 for bow type (id, name)
1 for shoot level (id, name)
1 table to link all above (id, ac_id, bt_id, sl_id)

So based on radio 1 being clicked and radio 2 being clicked, I want to fire a query on the link table to only get the shooting levels which belong to the 2 radio values..

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#age').click(function(){
    var age = $(this).val();
    var bow = $('#bow').val();

    function getShootingLevel(age, bow);
});

$('#bow').click(function(){
    var age = $('#age').val();
    var bow = $(this).val();

    function getShootingLevel(age, bow);
});

function getShootingLevel(age, bow)
{
    // ajax call
}
```

P.S. You can also check if radio is selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

I got it :)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=leeftijdscategorie]').change(function() {
        if($('input[type=radio][name=leeftijdscategorie]').is(':checked')) {
            if($('input[type=radio][name=schiettechniek]').is(':checked')) {
                //  Do stuff
                GetLevels($('input[name=leeftijdscategorie]:checked', '#inschrijfformulier').val(),$('input[name=schiettechniek]:checked', '#inschrijfformulier').val())
            }
        }
    });
    $('input[type=radio][name=schiettechniek]').change(function() {
        if($('input[type=radio][name=schiettechniek]').is(':checked')) {
            if($('input[type=radio][name=leeftijdscategorie]').is(':checked')) {
                //  Do stuff
                GetLevels($('input[name=leeftijdscategorie]:checked', '#inschrijfformulier').val(),$('input[name=schiettechniek]:checked', '#inschrijfformulier').val())
            }
        }
    });
});
function removeOptions(selectbox) {
    var i;
    for(i = selectbox.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
}

function GetLevels(agetype,bowtype) {
    removeOptions(document.getElementById(\"schietklasse\"));
    $.ajax({

        url: '/info/wscript.php',
        data: 
           {
            agetype: agetype, 
            bowtype: bowtype
           },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json', // returns response data as json// 

        success: function(output) {
            var selectBox = document.getElementById(\"schietklasse\");
            var options = output; //JSON.parse(output);
            for(var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++){
                var option = options[i];
                selectBox.options.add( new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected) );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I basically made this radio check seperate (so double) because I want people to be able to change their choice. Now, it fires a POST to a php file which gets the information and returns it as JSON.